# Route OpenVPN clients to another different OpenVPN server

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn

I have this scenario..

1. Server(Primary) with a multiple OpenVPN connections (so server is
   connected as a client to multiple OpenVPN servers.. lets say
   secondary servers)
2. This server runs OpenVPN server as well

Now what I need is Client will connect to that OpenVPN(Primary)server with username/pass.. depending on that username the server will route all traffic for that client to specified (secondary)OpenVPN server

Is there a way howto do this using `iptables`?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want:

```
one specific secondary VPN server to become the default gateway for a given client.
```

If this is so, that can be done using route push. You already know that you can tell the client the address of its "new" gateway after the OpenVPN connection has gone up.

Well, you can do so **dynamically**.

From the [manual](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html):

> --client-connect script
>   Run script on client connection. The script is passed **the common name** and IP address of the just-authenticated client as environmental
>   variables (see environmental variable section below). The script is
>   also passed the pathname of a not-yet-created temporary file as $1
>   (i.e. the first command line argument), to be used by the script **to
>   pass dynamically generated config file directives back to OpenVPN**.
>
> If the script wants to generate a dynamic config file to be applied on the server when the client connects, it should write it to
>   the file named by $1.
>
> See the --client-config-dir option below for options which can be legally used in a dynamically generated config file.
>
> Note that **the return value of script is significant**. If script returns a non-zero error status, it will cause the client to be disconnected.

So all you need to do is maintain a list of (client-common-name, default-gateway) entries, and prepare a `client-connect` script that will check out the client's name and prepare the appropriate `push "route-gateway a.b.c.d"` to be sent to OpenVPN server, and from there to the client.

You can also put `ip` commands into the script, but perhaps you do not need them.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Connect script for OpenVPN. This is /usr/local/bin/openvpn-connect-script.sh
# and OpenVPN server requires the extra option
#
#     --connect-client /usr/local/bin/openvpn-connect-script.sh
#

$script="$1"

# We could even fetch this from, say, a MySQL database.
# GATEWAY=$( echo "SELECT gateway FROM users_config WHERE user='$username';" \
#     | mysql -N openvpn )

case "$username" in
    "lserni")
        GATEWAY=192.168.168.192
        ;;
    "apiraino")
        GATEWAY=192.168.170.133
        ;;
    "*")
        GATEWAY=192.168.172.1
        ;;
esac

cat <<-CONFIG > $script

# Extra options, user-dependant.

gateway $GATEWAY

CONFIG

exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. but in my opinion this will not work because each client will be connected through the primary VPN server which is in another subnet.. it means in my opinion that the client needs to have set default route/gateway to IP of that primary openVPN server and then the traffic needs to be somehow forwarded between the client and the established OpenVPN link on the primary server or is it not correct?

Comment: any idea howto do it?

Comment: I've added a sample script as garnered from the manual notes. Let me know how it does.